# Move RavenDb to another server

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I have RavenDb database on some server. Now I need to move it to another server. Should I copy all the files inside Data directory or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying the content of the Data folder is not supported. The recomended way to do it is by using the Smuggler tool included in the RavenDB distribution package.

See http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/export-import

Answer (score 5):

You only need to copy the data directory and the tenants directory if you have multiple databases. Alternatively you can also export and import your database from the GUI, which is what I suggest since you only have one file you need to copy then.